# Cannot find EnableIEHosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am hosting an ASP.NET web application on a windows server. I cannot access the site through any Internet Explorer. I found some possible fixes and one that came up was enabling the EnableIEHosting under the registry. I cannot find the EnableIEHosting registry key under the server's register editor. Also is it safe for to add it on my own under both paths?

Paths Check:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\.NETFramework
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework
```

Server Specifications:

- Windows: 2012 R2
- .Net 4.5
- 64x
- Hosted through IIS

Comment: is there any error returns?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @reds Unfortunately not. But I will mention that it did work with one or two internet explorer clients. But most of them do not seem to work.

Comment: No any returns? How you open it? to its own machine or another machine?

Comment: @reds it's hosted by a company called ITOC. It's not my own machine. I can have them take a look at it but want to try everything possible before then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EnableIEHosting` registry value needs to exist on the client, not on the server. It is of type DWORD and would be set to 1 if you want to enable it. As you mentioned, it exists under keys

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\.NETFramework
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework
```